# React Material, have different colors in Label attribute for Material Tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material Tabs, and want the label to have a different colors within. I want Product Information to be black (regular text) and the asterisk to be red.  How can this be done in label?

```
<Tabs
    value={this.state.tabIndex}
    onChange={this.handleTabChange}
>
    <Tab label="Visit Information" />
    <Tab
       label={`Product Information ${this.state?.productFlag ? '*' : ''}`}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tab/) says, you can use a node (element) for `label` prop in `Tab` component. So, try this:

```
<Tab
  label={<span>Product Information <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.state.productFlag ? '*' : ''}</span></span>}
/>
```